# Extract data from SQL and send it as API

Tags: ssis

I have written a query in ssis (in dataflow task, OLE DB SOURCE) and result is a table. Now how can I send this result as API to my colleague every day and automatically? Would you please explain next steps? As I know there is no way to transform SQL result to JSON.

I have tried ssis web service task editor but there is a lot of field and I don't know them very well.

Comment: You don't "send" API's. API's sit there and wait for you to access them. Maybe you just want to send a flat file extract to your colleague?

Comment: SSIS is the wrong tool to be building API's in (I assume you mean a web API?) You could if you like pre generate the JSON as exaplained below and have it sitting there to be statically served by a web server, but this is not a real API since for example you can't pass in parameters etc.

Comment: @nick.mcdermiad thanks for your response, no a have sent data as a flat file for 2month but recently they ask to send data to them by API

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the OLE DB Source in SSIS Data Flow Task doesn't directly output JSON. You can use a Script Component in the Data Flow Task to transform the SQL result into JSON. Inside the Script Component, you can write custom code to convert the incoming data rows into a JSON format.

Add a Script Component Transformation to your Data Flow Task after the OLE DB Source. Then, configure the input and output columns in the Script Component.
You can use C# or VB.NET code within the Script Component's script editor to convert the input data rows into JSON format. You must build a JSON object/array and append the data accordingly.

After you have converted the SQL result to JSON format using the Script Component, you can save the JSON data to a file on your system or store it in an SSIS variable.

You can use SQL Server Agent to schedule the execution of your SSIS package.

As you mentioned, your colleague will need a Web API endpoint to receive the JSON data : this endpoint should be able to handle HTTP requests and process the JSON data received from your SSIS package.

If the previous steps are too complex or you prefer an alternative approach, consider using the SSIS Web Service Task Editor. While you mentioned it has many fields, it could still be a viable option. To use it, you need a Web API endpoint that accepts the data in a specific format (XML or JSON) and configure the Web Service Task to send the data to that endpoint.